# Exceptions in ListView rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have a ListView with the first column components being RadioButtons and the third column being TextBoxs. The second column is just a Label. I have all this working fine.
The problem is that I want the last row to be different. All I wanted was the second column to be a TextBox instead of a label. The content of the listview is binded with a XmlDataProvider.

Here it is the XmlDataProvider:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Properties" XPath="/Info">
    <x:XData>
        <Info xmlns="">
            <Property Name="Text" Value=""/>                
            <Property Name="Tooltip" Value=""/>             
            <Property Name="Enable" Value=""/>              
            <Property Name="Visible" Value=""/>             
            <Property Name="Focus" Value=""/>               
            <Property Name="Selected" Value=""/>            
            <Property Name="Count" Value=""/>               
            <Property Name="Item" Value=""/>                
            <Property Name="SelectedText" Value=""/>        
            <Property Name="SelectedIndex" Value=""/>       
            <Property Name="Complete" Value=""/>            
            <Property Name="Custom" Value=""/>
        </Info>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

And the ListView definition:

```
<ListView Name="lstProperties"  Margin="55 0 0 0" Style="{DynamicResource TsListView}"
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Properties}, XPath=Property}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TsListViewItem}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    SelectionMode="Single" IsEnabled="False"
    SelectionChanged="propertySelected" 
    >

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource FirstCell}" Width="25" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Property" Width="80">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Style="{DynamicResource TsLabel}" Height="25" Width="115" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="130">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TsHelperTextBox}"
                                 Height="20" Width="115" Text="{Binding XPath=@Value}" 
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=rbTypeAssert, Path=IsChecked}" GotFocus="gridTextBox_GotFocus" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I wanted the Property Custom to be presented in a TextBox instead of a Label.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer that works just fine at the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/11620a99-9c58-44e3-b0a9-146f7c39aea7).